# Use read_csv from pandas to create an instance of a child class of pandas.DataFrame in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, oop, inheritance

I'm adding some functionality to `pandas.DataFrame` by inheritance:

```
import pandas as pd
class my_class(pd.DataFrame):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
    def my_func(self):
        print('New function!')
```

But I'd still like to use `pandas.read_csv` to load the data frame. I checked here and it seems that simply changing the `__class__` of a `pandas.DataFrame` instance to `my_class` is discouraged. Is there a better way to do this? Thank you!

---

Specifically for the classes referenced above I can use the `data` parameter in `pandas.DataFrame.__init__` to pass the result of `pandas.read_csv` in, but what can I should I do if that parameter is not available?

Comment: by the way `super().__init__(*args)` is less redundant

Comment: `read_csv` is a module method so called by `pd.read_csv`, add a classmethod/static to your custom class... or I missed smt? [the link is not clickable] and the `self` in  `super().__init__(self, *args)` is still reduntant

Comment: @cards I'm trying to create a function that behaves like `pd.read_csv` but returns an instance of `my_class` which is a child class of `pd.DataFrame`. Essentially casting but it seems to be frowned upon in Python (or I could be wrong about that).

Comment: I personally would make the function as smt independent of the instance (that's also why is a module function and not part of DataFrame) so as class/static method... or even as external function. Try to edit the question with what you think it should be... ("behaves like" is quite ambiguous!)

Answer (score 2):

In your class declaration you are missing `def __new__(cls,...)` dunder method to initialize the instances. This should work:

```
import pandas as pd
class my_class(pd.DataFrame):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().__new__(cls)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    def my_func(self):
        print('New function!')
```

Not sure, it thats what it is asked for, but if you create your own `pandas.DataFrame` you can "convert" a fresh "read_csv(file)" read DataFrame to a custom one by initializing it after reading. So with the above declaration this works:

```
my_class({'test_col': [1,2,3]}).to_csv('test_my_class.csv')

df = pd.read_csv('test_my_class.csv')

my_class(df)
```

Comment: what happen to the *args and  **kwargs in `__new__`? They are not used in your code... and make `{'test_col': [1,2,3]}` totally useless

Comment: @cards I am not fully certain about it, but I guess they get passed to `__init__`, because if there is a `__new__` it gets executed first and triggers `__init__`. If you run `my_class({'test_col': [1,2,3]})` it returns a `my_class` style DataFrame.

Comment: my bad, it works but am not sure why;)

Comment: what confused me is that `{'test_col': [1,2,3]}` is processed by `__init__`